# Loop over custom defined class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, iterator

I made a class `file` to hold some properties of a file:

```
class file:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.path = filepath
        self.name = self.getName()
        self.type = self.getType()

    def getName(self):
        return Path(self.path).stem

    def getType(self):
        return 'some filetype'

    def getContent(self):
        with open(self.path, 'rt') as fid:
            return fid.read()
```

Now I want to store the properties of many files, and get a certain property of all files easily, so I made a `files` class:

```
class files:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.list)

    def add(self, file):
        self.list.append(file)

    def getNames(self):
        return [file.name for file in self.list]

    def getTypes(self):
        return [file.type for file in self.list]

    def getPaths(self):
        return [file.path for file in self.list]
```

This allows me to get all the file names by doing

```
somefiles = files()
somefiles.add(file('src/test.txt')) # and some other

filenames = somefiles.getNames()
```

By implementing the `__iter__` method, this also allows me to loop over the list in the `files` by just doing:

```
for file in somefiles:
    pass
```

Is this a pythonic way of looping over 'subobjects' of a class? It seems a bit weird to store my `file` instances in a list, and then converting this to an iterable by doing `iter(self.list)`. What would be the pythonic way?

Comment: `yield from self.list`?

Comment: Before asking yourself if there is a more pythonic way to do X, ask yourself what is *not* pythonic about X in the first place. Even `for x in [1,2,3]: ...` works because `iter([1,2,3])` returns a object of type `list_iterator`, not the list itself.

Comment: @DanielMesejo that works!

Comment: @chepner, i.e. it doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes this is a perfectly normal way to do this. Don't create a pointless generator when list_iterator objects already exist.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions 
Change  your class naming tho

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What do you mean?

Comment: @nexla will do, thx!